# or it is possible to encrypt or hide .js files content in html

Tags: javascript

I have made a html login page for my webpage. I am using Miniweb (simplest html server). All passwords and login data is saved to file.js but using the browser dev tools it is possible to see all passwords. I would like to know how I can encrypt or hide files from this tool.

Comment: Roberts, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn why this question isn't considered high quality.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript files used in your webpage can never be hidden from the user. The user can at any time open the developer tools and head for sources as you stated. JavaScript isn't a secure way to store passwords and sensitive data. Using a database is much safer. It would be saved on the server such that users cannot access it.

Comment: ok. Than i need to find some php server software to use a database. I'm  dont know how to set my Windows server 2003 to support PHP. i am beginner yet.  i have tried some PHP software but it is hard to find something what can run on this old system.

Comment: Try www.000webhost.com. They offer free website hosting with PHP support.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this. But typically, you wouldn't want the information on the actual html file. You could use webpack and something called uglify that takes all the javascript and scrambles it so it's unreadable.

But this is still shrieking security vulnerability. You would want to have the login information saved in a back end. The password itself should never be saved in it's pure form, anywhere where the public can access it.

Look into simple node servers. You can setup a quick database to store your information. Additionally, before you save the data, you encrypt it. and save the encryption. There's a module called bcrypt that helps with that.

When you login, you encrypt your login password again and compare it to the saved encryption. That way if you're database is ever compromised, all they'll see is a hash, not your actual password.

Additionally, traffic to and from your server and front end can still be intercepted, there's methods to encrypt the body of the requests and responses as well. So only the server can decrypt traffic coming out of the front end. Look into PKI and Certificates to learn more about that stuff. It's a pretty deep and heavy subject but clever as hell.

Comment: ok thanks, I think i try to find PHP software and try to set up database.